# Ref inside useEffect being null on first load

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I am trying to build a custom hook called `useInView` to track elements visibility but the state doesn't change until a hot reload is triggered not in the initial mount

```js
export default function useInView<T extends Element>(
  opts?: IntersectionObserverInit
) {
  const ref = useRef<T>(null!);
  const [inView, setInView] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect', ref.current);
    let el: T | null = null;
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
        setInView(entry.isIntersecting)
    }, opts);
    if (ref.current) {
      observer.observe(ref.current);
      el = ref.current;
    }
    return () => {
      if (el) observer.unobserve(el);
    };
  }, [opts]);
  return { ref, inView };
}
```

When running console.log() I get ref.current as null but when page is hot reloaded the ref.current is populated and the logic is working fine. What's the issue in my code ?

Comment: Refs changing don't trigger effects in any case.

Comment: How can I refactor this code to work properly?

Comment: Use a `state` instead of ref in that case.